# Scipy sawtooth wave non constant peak

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing, waveform

I wrote a simple code which generates a sawtooth wave and plots it. Here it is:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as ss
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Fs = 44100 # sampling frequecy
seconds = 2 #length of input
signal_frequency = 10

#input signal
t = np.arange(0, seconds, step = 1/Fs)
input_signal = ss.sawtooth(2 * np.pi * signal_frequency * t)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(t, input_signal)
plt.ylim(-2, 2)
plt.show()
```

Which gives me the following expected result:
[image: Sawtooth 10 Hz]
A nice 10 Hz 2 seconds long sawtooth wave with peak value of 1.

However, I noticed that if i change my sawtooth frequency to hundreds of Hz with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as ss
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Fs = 44100 # sampling frequecy
seconds = 2 #length of input
signal_frequency = 600

#input signal
t = np.arange(0, seconds, step = 1/Fs)
input_signal = ss.sawtooth(2 * np.pi * signal_frequency * t)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(t, input_signal)
plt.ylim(-2, 2)
plt.show()
```

I get this plot (it is zoomed in):
[image: saw non costant]
As you might notice, my sawtooth wave has not a constant peak value of 1 anymore.

I debugged the code and it seems fine. Why is this happening? Is it due to the sampling frequency?

Comment: If the sampling frequency does not exactly match (hormonics-wise) the signal frequency you will get some sort of 'beat' between the two.  And will be especially obvious with a sawtooth signal like this, the peak is so narrow.

Comment: Oh yes, this makes perfectly sense. I totally forgot about this common problem, spectral leakage.... However if you want to elaborate it and add an answer I will accept it